# Create View with option (maxrecursion)?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I get a "Incorrect syntax near keyword 'OPTION'" error when attempting to save a view in SQL Server 2012. I'm trying to add a MAXRECURSION option to the end of my common table expression. All the examples I've seen and working CTEs I've created before don't mind the "OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)" at the end of the CTE.

Anyone see why I'm getting this error? The CTE works without the OPTION clause, although it reaches the maximum number of recursions (100).

```
WITH CTE1 AS (select
       t.[ID_DIM_PRODUIT]
      ,t.[ID_FACTURE]
          ,t.[date_facture]
          ,t.[quantite]

      ,t.[quantite_enstock]
    from [dbo].[Fact_Stock] t
 cross apply (select sum([quantite_enstock]) as stockTotal 
                from [dbo].[Fact_Stock]
                where [ID_DIM_PRODUIT] = t.[ID_DIM_PRODUIT]
                and [date_facture] <= t.[date_facture]
            ) as st),
DateList (ID_FACTURE,ID_DIM_PRODUIT,stockTotal,date_facture,stockDateEnd  )
AS (
SELECT ID_FACTURE,ID_DIM_PRODUIT,stockTotal,date_facture 
      , LEAD(date_facture, 1) OVER ( PARTITION BY ID_DIM_PRODUIT ORDER BY date_facture ) AS stockDateEnd
    FROM CTE1
UNION ALL
SELECT ID_FACTURE,ID_DIM_PRODUIT,mvtStock,stockTotal,DATEADD(DAY,1,date_facture),stockDateEnd  FROM DateList
WHERE DATEADD(DAY,1,date_facture) < stockDateEnd
) 
SELECT  d.id_facture,d.ID_DIM_PRODUIT,d.stockTotal ,d.date_facture as date_stock  ,t.[ID_FACT_STOCK]

      ,t.[id_dim_fournisseur]
      ,t.[id_dim_depot]

      ,t.[poidnetGlobal]
      ,t.[poidsBrutGloba]
      ,t.[quantite]
      ,t.[montant_HT]
      ,t.[montant_TTC]
      ,t.[cout_moyen_unitaire]

      ,t.[mvtStock]
      ,t.[prix_vente_unitaire]
      ,t.[prix_achat]
      FROM DateList d , CTE1 t where  
        d.id_facture=t.ID_FACTURE and d.ID_DIM_PRODUIT=t.ID_DIM_PRODUIT ORDER BY ID_DIM_PRODUIT,date_stock
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Comment: ready to get sad? you can't include option(something) in a view.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis But I believe you can declare an increment count column and specify WHERE count <= X.

Comment: I would suggest that you ask *another* question, specifically about the recursive CTE and the fact that you want to store it in a view (where the option is not allowed).  There may be other ways to write the logic you need, but figuring out the logic out from your query is a lot to ask of anyone.